# Wamp service not getting started after vhost setting

Tags: localhost, wamp, virtualhost

Recently I had made some changes in httpd-vhosts file to create a virtual host. After which the wamp icon status no turning to green, hence remains orange. Ive cheked for other http programs if had been run through TEST PORT80, but found no programs to be run. I guess there might be some mistake when I configured for virtual hosts. Below is what i'd tried before the wamp had stopped working. Please tell me if the configuration done was correct or incorrect. Please suggest some solution for configuring vhosts file in am wrong.

This is lines I inluded in httpd-vhosts file

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
   ServerName tastingroom.com
  #ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
   ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
   DocumentRoot "c:\wamp\www"
   ServerName tastingroom.com
   ServerAlias www.tastingroom.com
   ErrorLog "logs/tastingroom-error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/tastingroom-access.log" common

 <directory "c:\wamp\www">
     Option Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOerride all
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.1     
 </directory>

 </VirtualHost>
```

And in "hosts" file inside system32 of Windows folder

```
enter code here

127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 tastingroom.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think same server name are allowed, can you please check apache error logs and see what error message it shows. Also, your VirtualHost entry should below and remove the first one as it is redundant

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
   DocumentRoot "c:\wamp\www"
   ServerName tastingroom.com
   ServerAlias www.tastingroom.com tastingroom.com
   ErrorLog "logs/tastingroom-error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/tastingroom-access.log" common

 <directory "c:\wamp\www">
     Option Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOerride all
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.1     
 </directory>

 </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know well about the commands,
but still I'll be suggesting you to follow because I've made it successful with the following procedure..

> This I've done in ubuntu pc's

In the terminal type the following

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts (then enter)
```

it may ask for password & later it opens the hosts file in that give the general IP as follows

```
127.0.0.1   project.local
```

next, execute the command

`cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled` (then enter)

it will look like `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled $`

then after

`sudo nano project.local`

make sure that the project.local must be same as that we have entered before..
Now,

```
<VirtualHost   *:80>
ServerName     project.local
DocumentRoot   /var/www/project
</VirtualHost>
```

finally..

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`